# How to add a custom class depending on a property value to the angular grid rows without rewriting the HTML for the whole row?

Tags: angularjs, gridview

How to add a custom class depending on a property value to the angular grid rows without rewriting the HTML for the whole row? I'm aware that you can rewrite the whole HTML with the gridOptions.rowTemplate value. But I just want to add a custom class without changing anything else.

ex:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: getColumnsDefs(),
    rowTemplate: 'whatever I put here changes the entire row.',
      ......
}
```

Comment: Add a code example to make it easier to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about `angular` (angular2+) not `anjularJS`?

Comment: Changed to angularjs